# Words with the hightest frequency that are not Collocates of each other (inside a text corpora)

Tags: corpora, frequency, collocations

Is there a way to obtain a:

- List, that has 2 words per row
- Each 2 words are not collocates (or collocations) of each other (ie: are not found within the same phrase inside the entire text corpus, or other collocates finding method).
- The list contains words that are really common (high frequency) but are not stop words
- The list is sorted by the rows that have the highest frequency words

To sum up, the idea is to find two words that are really common but are almost never used together

Comment: By Zipf's Law, you'll end up with a certain number of hapaxes in any large corpus. My guess is your least-common pairs will be nothing but hapaxes.

Comment: You're looking for n-gram counts or frequencies.  The most infrequent 2-grams are those that never occur even once.  And in most corpora that is most of them.

Comment: Do you know Python?

Comment: @Draconis: You are right. Maybe I could create a weighted rank, that accounts for individual rank (high) vs combined rank (low).

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: It has to do with the previous comment, you are right. I need highest rank words with lowest combined rank (weighted rank).
I once studied Python, but I could re-learn the things I might need for this.

Comment: Another keyword to help you identify relevant literature: collocations

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer to your question *find the pair of words that never appear together, and have the highest individual frequency (the sum of them)*:

Using the [Penn Treebank](https://web.archive.org/web/19970614160127/http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/) as a text corpus, the top 10 pairs are:

```
 (8090, 'the', 'the'),
 (6364, 'the', 'of'),
 (6209, 'the', 'to'),
 (5923, 'the', 'a'),
 (5923, 'a', 'the'),
 (5617, 'the', 'in'),
 (5556, 'the', 'and'),
 (5168, 'the', '*-1'),
 (5168, '*-1', 'the'),
 (5144, 'the', '0')
```

The result should be quite intuitive.

Code:

```
import nltk, string
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('ptb')

tokens = nltk.corpus.treebank.words()
ct = Counter(tokens)
tokens_high_freq = [x for x in ct if ct[x]>10 ]
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(tokens)
bigram_dict = defaultdict(list)
for a,b in bigrams:
    bigram_dict[a].append(b)

bigrams_never = [(ct[a]+ct[b],a,b) for a in tokens_high_freq for b in tokens_high_freq 
                 if b not in bigram_dict[a] and a not in string.punctuation and b not in string.punctuation]
print(sorted(bigrams_never, reverse=True)[:10])
```

-- Edit --

Corrected a coding mistake, thanks to @FrédéricGrosshans.

Comment: In term of frequency, the expected frequency of a bigram (assuming uniform random distribution), so it would probably be more relevant to compare to the *product* of frequencies. 
I am also surprised to see the following pairs in your list of missing pairs, as they seem natural to me : “of the”, "in the", "to the"

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans Regarding missing<"of","the"> etc: you are correct, I made a silly mistake in the program. Now corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If comparing the*product* instead of the *sum*, the top 7 pairs are still the same, and from 8 to 10 becomes: (5377761, 'of', 'of'),  (5018316, 'to', 'of'),  (5018316, 'of', 'to').

Comment: How does your program account for hyphenation? Because while "the to " and "the in " are probably forbidden by English grammar rules, there are things like "the to-do list" or "the in-laws". Are they instances of "the to" and "the in", or should they be counted as "the to-do" and "the in-laws"?

Comment: @LuísHenrique Current program treats "to-do" as a single token, which is consistent with the default NLTK treebank tokenizer. The only 2 instances in the corpus matching the "the *-*" pattern are both "the over-the-counter".

Comment: Thanks for your answer and to people who added info to it. I might have made a mistake, since English is not my native language. I tried to clarify that it was "in the same text", and not actually one after the other. What I mean is, for example, that both words are not seen on the same phrase, or the same paragraph, or whatever is the easiest to do.

Comment: To explain a little bit further. It's for a research in marketing, where there is a theory that says that a good tool for naming a brand, with high seo and still be easy to remember for customers, is to have two common words that are not often seen together. So I'm trying to take this to the extreme, and find the most common words that are not seen inside the same text in a corpus, to then use this for the project, and test the relevance of this theory.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a programming language, you can count the [bi-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) yourself.

For example for Python you can install the [language](https://github.com/SignalN/language) package with `pip install language`.

Then in Python:

```
import language.ngrams as ng
ngrams = ng.word_ngrams(text, n=2)

import collections
counts = collections.Counter(ngrams)
```

Note that this will not give you the truly least frequent 2-grams: those which never occur even once, the vast majority of them.

Now do a sanity check.

```
counts.most_common()
len(counts)
```

Then there are a few ways to get the least common, the best way depends on the size of your dataset.

```
least_frequent = sorted(counts, key=counts.get, reverse=False)
least_frequent[:10] # first 10
```

However my guess is that what you want is more like a language model, which can tell you which common words make uncommon n-grams, or what are the most uncommon n-grams given a word.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I can now program it with the concepts that you provided:
- Since I know which is the lower frequency for the pairs (0), I can discard any pair that appears in the same text. This will give me a faster process (since I don't have to search in the next texts, because that pair is already discarded).
- I want to avoid hapaxes, so I will ignore words with low frequency (again, a faster process).
- What I want to find is the pair of words that never appear together, and have the highest individual frequency (the sum of them).

Comment: @FernandoKuster Makes sense.  When you have it, then maybe come back and answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are focussing on *texts* and not just pairs of words occurring in sequence, I suggest using [topic modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) as a tool to analyse your texts. The different topics have some overlap in the words occurring there (mainly stop words), but word from different topics tend to to avoid each other.